# How to compare 2 row in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

please help,
this is  my table

```
   date     column1    column2          trx
2015-07-01  **side1    Internet**     777903315
2015-07-01  **side1    Internet**      41426210
2015-07-01  side1      Unlimited        2263500
2015-07-01  side1      Business          427000 
2015-07-01  side1      Extreme          3540900
2015-07-01  side1      Lifestyle       59360000
2015-07-01  side1      Socialita      240850500
2015-07-01  **side2    Unlimited**         6160
2015-07-01  **side2    Unlimited**    113502000
```

and i want to select my table with result like this :

```
   date     column1    column2          trx      type
2015-07-01  **side1    Internet**     777903315  pre
2015-07-01  **side1    Internet**      41426210  post
2015-07-01  side1      Unlimited        2263500  pre
2015-07-01  side1      Business          427000  pre
2015-07-01  side1      Extreme          3540900  pre
2015-07-01  side1      Lifestyle       59360000  pre
2015-07-01  side1      Socialita      240850500  pre
2015-07-01  **side2    Unlimited**         6160  post
2015-07-01  **side2    Unlimited**    113502000  pre
```

row that have same value in column1 and column2 with row after the minimum trx add field as type 'post' and the maximun 'pre'

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? seems to me a case statement with a left self join or a subquery might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @PKirby he posted raw data from his table, and then the order in which he wanted to display the records. that's what he's asking. 
Now i see that there are different answers so maybe it wasn't that clear.
I understood that he wanted it ordered by column1 and then column2 while disregarding the postfix

Comment: @eranotzap Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @PKirby the ** mark is just for sign that the rows has the same value...
the rows that has same values with different in trx column must be specified in another column as type, 'pre' with max value and 'post' with min value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.date, t.c1, t.c2, t.trx
     , CASE WHEN t.trx = m.trx THEN 'pre' ELSE 'post' END AS `type`
  FROM so_q31531850 t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DATE, c1, c2, MAX(trx) AS trx FROM so_q31531850 GROUP BY 1,2,3) m 
               ON m.trx = t.trx AND m.c1 = t.c1 AND m.c2 = t.c2 AND m.date = t.date
```

Please note that, if the transaction number is same, my suggested query treats it as `post` type of entry.

Comment: the transaction number is different, that why i want to add `type` column

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT m.*,       
       CASE trx 
          WHEN mintrx THEN 'post'
          WHEN maxtrx THEN 'pre'
          ELSE 'pre'
       END AS type
FROM mytable AS m
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT column1, column2, MIN(trx) AS mintrx, MAX(trx) AS maxtrx
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY column1, column2
   HAVING MIN(trx) <> MAX(trx) ) AS t
ON m.column1 = t.column1 AND m.column2 = t.column2
```

This query performs a `LEFT JOIN` with a derived table containing only duplicate `column1`, `column2` rows. Minimum / maximum `trx` matches produce `post` / `pre` values respectively, whereas `pre` is the default value for non-matched table rows.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abf72/3)

Comment: i didnt know, but when i use your query, some data didnt catch the pre and post

Comment: @daffy In that case your real data differs from your sample data. Can you post an excerpt containing such 'not caught' data?

Answer (score 0):

Below query(SQL) gives the result in above given required format:

```
SELECT Date,column1,column2,trx
 ,CASE RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Date,col1,col2 ORDER BY trx DESC)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'pre'
  ELSE 'post'
  END as type
FROM [TableName]
```

Comment: `RANK` is not available in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code be done a bit better, I'm not an sql person myself but it was fun the fiddle with.

Here's a sample table :

```
 CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
     id INT,
     c1 NVARCHAR(100), 
     c2 NVARCHAR(100)         
   );

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (1, '**side1', 'Internet**');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (2, '**side2', 'Unlimited**');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (3, 'side1', 'Unlimited');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (4, 'side1', 'Lifestyle');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (5, 'side1', 'Buisness');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (6, '**side2', 'Unlimited**');

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID,c1,c2)
VALUES (7, '**side1', 'Internet**');
```

The query :

```
select * from Example 
order by 
   case 
      when c1 like '**%' then substring(c1,3,Len(c1)) else c1   
   end,c1 ,c2 desc;
```

Comment: the ** is just as sign that the rows has the same value in some column